# AJAX Submission on submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this for my comment.php:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(function() {    
 $('#reset_form').click(function() {
     $('#name,#comment').val('');
 });
 $('#submit').click(function() {

var name = $('#name').val();
var comment = $('#comment').val();

$.ajax({
    url: '../forms/comment_ajax.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>',
    data: { form_name: name, form_comment: comment },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#new_comment').append(data);

        $(document).trigger('close.facebox');

        $('#new_comment').effect("bounce", { direction:'down', times:5 }, 300);        
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 2000, "easeOutQuart");
        return false;
    }
});
});
});

</script>

Name: <br />
<input type="text" id="name" class="userpass" maxlength="15"/><br /><br />

Comment: <br />
<textarea id="comment" rows="6" cols="75"></textarea><br /><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit class="button" value="Comment" />
<input type="reset" name="submit" value="Reset"/>
```

Then this for my AJAX:

```
<?php
require_once('../blog/inc/config.php');

    $form_name = $_GET['form_name'];
    $form_comment = htmlspecialchars($_GET['form_comment']);
    $date = date('M jS Y | g:i a T');
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

     if($form_name == '') {
        echo("<div class='alert alert-error-x'>Don't forget to enter your name, as we need to identify who's commenting on this article!</div>");

    } else if($form_comment == '') {
        echo("<div class='alert alert-error-x'>Please do not leave the comment field blank, we want to know what you're saying!</div>");

    } else {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (id, articleid, name, comment, date, ip) VALUES (NULL,'{$_GET['id']}','{$form_name}','{$form_comment}','{$date}','{$ip}')");

        // output comment
        echo "
  <div class='article-body-new'>
  <div class='user'><b>$form_name</b> <span>says:</span></div> 
  <div class='comments'>
  $form_comment <br /><p></p><br />

  <p style='font-size:12px;'>Posted on <b><font size='0.8em'>$date</font></b></p>
  </div>
  </div>";
    }
?>
```

I have this working on a facebox js, and this is what it'll look like: http://screencloud.net/v/m9jR

But once you try to post, it won't post the content. I keep clicking "comment", but it won't execute.

My full article.php page is here: http://pastebin.com/DCHGR1Ly

Would you guys happen to know what it is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the return false inside of the success callback is wrong, it needs to go outside of that.

Comment: something like: pastebin.com/eZiRX8bt excuse my ignorance when it comes to coding, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly don't return false in the success method. It won't do anything useful.

Secondly add a e.preventDefault() on the click event. That method call lets the default action of the event not be triggered.

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
```

**Edit**

I also noticed that the JavaScript might be executing before the DOM is ready. Please move all JS to just before the `</body>`. And consider to use something like `$(document).ready(function () {...`.

Comment: something like: http://pastebin.com/eZiRX8bt excuse my ignorance when it comes to coding, haha.